# How to copy paste between Android and Windows?

Tags: windows, android, copy-paste

I just want Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V work across all devices: from Windows to Android and from Android to Windows. Be it just a text or a file ([like this in pushbullet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGb7MU-eg9k), but for pushbullet, universal copy paste is premium feature.)

I am trying AirDroid. What all I found related to this is this:
[image]

I have to do Ctrl+C, then open this app, go to relevant device tab and click these buttons.

**Q1.** Is this the procedure? Cant I just do Ctrl+C on windows and long press and paste on android. Also copying from Android's clipboard to Windows did not work while the other way worked everytime.

**Q2.** Is this any way around. Is there any better software which does it for free, for text and files, without lag, on same network devices?

Comment: Well, Q1 is off-topic here. This site is about recommending software to meet your requirements – not to explain how you should use software you already have. As for Q2: there are multiple [cross-device clipboard apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_clipboard#group_43) available, take your pick. I'm not using any such, so I cannot recommend one.